# Batch file to run a command by pulling input files from another text file and output a separate file for each loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to download files from a lfs system using `mcumgr`, but I have a lot of files to download so I was trying to use a batch file.

This is the gist of the command to download:

`mcumgr ....fs download /lfs/log/%%x %%x`

`%%x` is the file name.

This is the batch file I was trying:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%x in (files.txt) DO (
    cmd /k "mcumgr ...fs download /lfs/log/%%x %%x"
)
```

I created a `files.txt`, where I paste the list of files to download; but it appends all the outputs into a single text file and I want to have separate output files every time it goes through the loop, *(similar to continually running the commands)*.

Edit: the list of files are similar to this:

```
86483ef-648274286.txt
7963476-647649836.txt
```

Any suggestions to go about this?

Comment: Is the content of `files.txt` simply the filename? Do any of the filenames contain a special character such as a SPACE? Why is `delims==` needed? Could you copy/paste 3 lines of files.txt into the question?

Comment: Should be no reason to need to use `CMD /K`.

Comment: @lit I added it! it's essentially a list a randomized mix of letters and numbers with a "-" in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was close. When the `mcumgr` command appears correct, remove the `ECHO` from the beginning of the line.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (files.txt) DO (
    ECHO mcumgr ...fs download "/lfs/log/%%~A" "%%~A"
)
```

If `mcumgr` is a .bat or .cmd script, then `CALL` should be used.

ECHO CALL mcumgr ...fs download "/lfs/log/%%~A" "%%~A"